# How to wait for all elements of ng-repeat to be displayed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, angularjs-ng-repeat, protractor

Panel Property Page:

```
this.IncList = element.all(by.repeater('list in $ctrl.all track by list.guid'));
```

Function to wait for List to be displayed:

```
exports.WaitUntilListDisplaye = function(){
    browser.wait(function(){
        Panel.IncList.isDisplayed();
    },10000);
};
```

If I use this function in my test to wait for all the items of the list to be displayed it, times out every time. Is there any way to wait until all the element of ng-repeat is displayed.

Answer (score 2):

You *don't return anything from inside the wait function* - hence the condition is always "falsy" and you get a timeout exception:

```
exports.WaitUntilListDisplayed = function(){
    browser.wait(function() {
        return Panel.List.isDisplayed();
    }, 10000);
};
```

Note that the page object field you've shown is called `IncList`, but you are using `List` inside the expected condition.

---

Also, you can use the [`by.exactRepeater`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.exactRepeater) and omit the "track by" part:

```
this.IncList = element.all(by.exactRepeater('list in $ctrl.all'));
```

Comment: I have changed function to return Panel.IncList.isDisplayed(); and using this function as: `CommonFun.WaitUntilListDisplaye().then(function(){
      IncidencePanel.IncList.count().then(function(count){
      console.log("count = "+count);}); });`  and get error   Failed: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: @soniasharma you are missing the "d" at the end of WaitUntilListDisplayed.

Comment: I am using WaitUntilListDisplaye function in my script.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Panel.List` returns multiple elements, you need to return a Promise evaluating that there is no `false` within the array returned by `isDisplayed()`:

```
browser.wait(function(){
  return Panel.List.isDisplayed().then(results => results.indexOf(false) == -1);
}, 5000, "some elements are not visible");
```

Comment: I tried the same function as you suggested, but getting following error: Failed: results.indexOf is not a function

Comment: The `Panel.IncList` in your example is an `element.all(...)`. My guess is that you changed it to return a single element `element(...)` or `element.all(...).get(n)`, which would explain the error.

Comment: `this.List = element.all(by.repeater('list in $ctrl.all track by list.guid'));` <br/>`this.ListLastItem = this.List.last();`<br/> I am using this: `browser.wait(function(){
  return Panel.ListLastItem .isDisplayed().then(results => results.indexOf(false) == -1);
}, 5000, "some elements are not visible");` but still I am getting  Failed: results.indexOf is not a function error

Comment: The call`this.List.last()` returns one element, which is why you are getting the error. To wait for a single element, use `browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(Panel.ListLastItem), 5000);`. http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.visibilityOf

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong with this wait statement if I use this implicit wait my script will verify the element before ListLastItem will be displayed and my test will fail, where as If I put explicit wait (browser.sleep(1000)) then all my test will pass.

Comment: Let me elaborate more my issue: In my script I am trying to search the List based on its Status, so when I click on search and select Search Type it will get result by the Rest API and once Rest API returns the result it will be updated in the UI. this complete thing will take 8-9ms time to update the UI hen I want to put implicit for the API to update the UI. How can I achieve this?